# Create a route to show a node with a custom display/view mode

Tags: 8, entities

In Drupal 8, it is easy to add display/view modes. Let say I created the *tech* display mode and I set it up for the *film* content type.

Now, I would like to create a route for it and access it as local task of entity.node.canonical.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Drupal 8 there are two display modes: view mode and form mode.

You can [define the view mode in a route](https://www.drupal.org/node/2092643) using the `_entity_view` key.

> _entity_view: The value is entity_type.view_mode. Will find an entity in the path and render it in the given view mode. E.g. _entity_view:
>   node.teaser will return the render array of the {node} in teaser mode.

Answer (score 1):

The [View Mode Page](https://www.drupal.org/project/view_mode_page) module does just what you're looking for, creating alternate paths to access different view modes.

> Create separate pages for different view modes for a given content
>   type.

Comment: The View Mode Page module worked perfectly for what I needed. Thanks for the very helpful tip!